# Replace string with optional trailing characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following `string` with various `HTML` tags inside:

```
let str = "3 HTML tags are: <html>, <a href src='www.google.com'>, and <body>.";
```

I want to replace each `HTML` tag with an arbitrary value outline within a `map`:

```
let map = {
   "<html>":"<HTML>",
   "<a*>":"<A HREF SRC='..'",
   "<body>":"<BODY>"
};
```

However, for certain tags like `<a href="..."`, I want to simply leave the `href` value intact and simply replace the `<a href="www.google.com">` with `<A HREF="www.google.com">`

I've tried to add wildcard characters inside the value for the respective key but it's just being hardcoded as an asterisk (`*`).

Is there a way to accomplish this? Any and all documentation is welcome!

My JSFiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kydeLdep/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). You can't relibaly use regular expressions to parse HTML because HTML is not a regular language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this

```
let str = "3 HTML tags are: <html>, <a href src='www.google.com'>, and <body>.";
let map = {
   "<html>":"<HTML>",
   "<a href src":"<A HREF SRC",
   "<body>":"<BODY>"
};
str = str.replace(/<html>|<a href src|<body>/gi, function(matched){
  return map[matched];
});

alert(str);
```

Comment: This doens't meet the criteria with respect to A elements, i.e. `<a href="www.google.com">` with `<A HREF="www.google.com">` since `<a href src` does not match `<a href=`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar on a side project. Consider a structure we can call `matcher` which are basically objects which the following structure

```
let matcher = {
    id: "htmlTag",
    pattern: "<html>", // This can be string or regexp
    replacer: "<HTML>", // This can be string or a function
}
```

We can have an array of such objects called `matchers` which we can iterate over and use the `str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)` to get the output we need.

```
let matchers = [...];
let str = "3 HTML tags are: <html>, <a href src='www.google.com'>, and <body>.";

matchers.forEach(function(matcher){
    console.log(`Before ${matcher.id}: ${str}`);
    str = str.replace(matcher.pattern, matcher.replacer)
    console.log(`After ${matcher.id}: ${str}`);
})
```

If you wanted to save the src attribute for a particular tag, for example, you could define a replacer function which gets the matched string which can be processed using string splitting/ regexp matching to build the new string needed (preserving the attributes we need etc).